# How does loop in recursion work?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm learning recursion now, and I thought I quite understood how recursion works, and then I saw this code, and my head is about to explode.

I know this simple recursion works like

```
public void recursivePrint(int number){
    if(number == 0{
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(number + " ");
    recursivePrint(number - 1);
    }
```

If the parameter "number"'s value is 2.

```
public void recursivePrint(2){
if(number == 0{
    return;
}
System.out.print(2 + " ");
recursivePrint(2 - 1);
}

public void recursivePrint(1){
if(number == 0{
    return;
}
System.out.print(1 + " ");
recursivePrint(1 - 1);
}
```

and then stops because it meets its base case.

What about this print all permutations of a string function?

```
private void permute(String str, int l, int r)
{
    if (l == r)
        System.out.println(str);
    else
    {
        for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
        {
            str = swap(str,l,i);
            permute(str, l+1, r);
            str = swap(str,l,i);
        }
    }
}
```

There is a recursive call inside a for loop. If the input value is "ab", how does this recursion function work? Can you explain as I wrote above?
I got this code form geeksforgeeks, and there's a video for this, but I can't understand this since I don't know how loop works in recursion.

Comment: Try stepping through it using a debugger or trace on paper.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion occurs when a method calls itself. Such a method is called recursive. A recursive method may be more concise than an equivalent non-recursive approach. However, for deep recursion, sometimes an iterative solution can consume less of a thread's finite stack space.

What is recursion:
In general, recursion is when a function invokes itself, either directly or indirectly. For example:

```
// This method calls itself "infinitely"
public void useless() {
useless(); // method calls itself (directly)
}
```

Conditions for applying recursion to a problem:
There are two preconditions for using recursive functions to solving a specific problem:

1. There must be a base condition for the problem, which will be the endpoint for the recursion. When a
   recursive function reaches the base condition, it makes no further (deeper) recursive calls.
2. Each level of recursion should be attempting a smaller problem. The recursive function thus divides the problem into smaller and smaller parts. Assuming that the problem is finite, this will ensure that the recursion terminates.

In Java there is a third precondition: it should not be necessary to recurse too deeply to solve the problem;

The following function calculates factorials using recursion. Notice how the method factorial calls itself within the function. Each time it calls itself, it reduces the parameter n by 1. When n reaches 1 (the base condition) the function will recurse no deeper.

```
public int factorial(int n) {
if (n <= 1) { // the base condition
return 1;
} else {
return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `permute` function you are generating strings where `l`th char is being replaced by one of the char following it. With the `for` loop inside it, you are touching onto each of those *following* characters one at a time.

With several call to `permute`, you are able to *advance* till the `end` position of the string, and that `end` is checked by `if (l == r)`

Take the case of `abc`.

```
                    abc
                /    |     \
Level 1    a(bc)    b(ac)    c(ba)   (Here three new call to permute are made out of permute with l=1)

Goes on...
```

FYI, permutation isn't that simple to understand if you are new to recursion or programming. For easy understanding use pen-paper.